# Isotope filtering (again)

Tags: jquery-isotope

Hi I would like to show only one filter (.one) when my page load.
Can't figure out how to do it - not very clever when it comes to js :(

My html:
class="isotop-filter" id="filters"

```
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-isotop is-checked" data-filter="*">All</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-isotop" data-filter=".one">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-isotop" data-filter=".two">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-isotop" data-filter=".three">3y</button>
               </div>
```

My js looks like this:

$(window).load(function() {

```
// Initialize Isotope

var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: 'li',
    //percentPosition: true
});


// Bind filter button click
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function(){
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ){
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function(){
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
});



//Hover Direction
$(function() {
    $('#da-thumbs').find('> li').each(function () {
        $(this).hoverdir({
            hoverDelay : 75
        });
    });
});
```

});